# mesos containerizer task are too slow

Tags: cassandra, mesos, mesosphere

I am running cassandra on mesos. Here I have two tasks running on mesos agent, one is cassandra task itself and second is restore data task. When I directly ssh into mesos agent and run restore data command (sstableloader), it completes within 2 minutes but when same command is invoked in restore data task container (mesos containerizer), it takes about 8 hours. I have allocated 12 cpus, 4 gb of ram and disk to that task out. I need to understand where is this containerizer property creating a bottleneck and how can I resolve it.

I have set stream throughput and compaction throughput 300 MB/s.

One theory, I have is the port restore task is using to communicate with cassandra task may be an issue.

Comment: Please provide some more information. Whats agent configuration. How command is launched?

Comment: Agent is 24 CPU, 124GB RAM and 2TB Disk. I am launching the task using mesosphere open source cassandra framework. I have two tasks running. One is cassandra task (20 CPU/80GB RAM) and second is custom task (2 CPU/4GB RAM). This is bit of cassandra detail, custom task first downloads 20 GB for sstable files, then tries to stream them to cassandra task. Here, I believe streaming huge chunk of data between task is slow.